# canvas should i use beginpath() with html5 lines

Tags: html, canvas, geometry

I know you can use `beginpath();` with circles in the canvas. However, from what I have been taught, you don't need to use it with lines. I sometimes don't use it with lines and it works perfectly fine, the same with adding `beginpath()`, still works fine. But should I be using `beginpath();` with lines? If so, what else? Is it a good or bad habit, tell me everything you know.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, use beginPath()**

beginPath() tells canvas that you are about to begin a new path--and toLine() is a path process.  Without beginPath(), your next drawings will bleed onto your previous drawings because canvas thinks you are still continuing those previous drawings.  Same goes for other path drawings like arc, arcTo, quadraticCurveTo, etc.